# .Copy 使用時のクラッシュ?

Tags: vba, excel

vbaで "Worksheets("シート名").Copy" 行(3行目)での処理時間が長いです。vbaを実行すればするほど、処理時間が長くなっているように感じます。

```
book = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Worksheets("シート名").Select
Worksheets("シート名").Copy
newbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Windows(book).Activate
Worksheets("シート名").Select

*****
処理
*****

Windows(newbook).Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="ファイル名" & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, 
CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
Windows(book).Activate
Worksheets("シート名").Select
Cells.Clear
```

ご存知の方がいましたら、ご教授いただけますと幸いでございます。

Comment: 前後のソースコードの掲示をお願いします。
現在のコードでは、"シート名"シートをコピーし、新規ブックに貼り付ける動きとなっていますが…

Comment: ご指摘いただきありがとうございます。変更させていただきました！

Comment: 対象のシートには何行くらいのデータが入っているのでしょうか？データの量によらず、Copyを使うと問題が起きる？また、参考までにOfficeのバージョンも追記してもらうとよいかもしれません。

Comment: データは1,000行くらいのデータが入っているときもあれば、10行くらいのデータが入っているときもあります。データ量によらず、Copyを使うと問題が起きます。さらに実行回数が増えるほど、処理時間が長くなっているようです。
バージョンは 「2016 mso 16.0.9126.2116 32ビット」です。